# JAVA "calculateFee cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm experiencing this issue with a Java Class. I'd like some guide please.

The issue is:

> calculateFee cannot be resolved to a type

AuctionSale.java

```
public class AuctionSale


  public double calculateFee() {

     if (takingOffers == true) {
        return 0;
     } else if (reservePrice > 0) {
        return reservePrice/20 + currentOffer/20;
     } else {
        return currentOffer/10;
     }
  }
```

AuctionSaleSystem.java

```
public class AuctionSaleSystem

 private static void displaySalesReport()
 {
      System.out.println("Current Auction Sales Report:");
  System.out.println();


  for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++) {
     String itemNumber = sales[i].getItemNumber();
     String description = sales[i].getDescription();
     Double brokerFee = 0.00;

     // Stuck at this point, not able to get past the error
     // "calculateFee cannot be resolved to a type"  :(
     calculateFee brokerFee = new calculateFee();

     brokerFee = brokerFee.calculateFee();


     System.out.printf("Item Number: %s, Description: %s, Broker fee: %d %n", 
                       itemNumber, description, brokerFee);
  }
}
```

Comment: why all the downvotes?

Comment: If I understood correctly `calculateFee()` is a non-static method of class `AuctionSale`. So to be able to call it you must first acquire an instance of this class. So it should go something like this: `AuctionSale brokerFee = new AuctionSale(); double fee = brokerFee.calculateFee();`

Answer (score 2):

calculateFee is a method not a type. Change to

```
AuctionSale brokerFee = new AuctionSale();
double result = brokerFee.calculateFee();

 System.out.printf("Item Number: %s, Description: %s, Broker fee: %d %n", 
                       itemNumber, description, result);
```

You should learn the Java Basics

Answer (score 2):

`calculateFee` is not a class it is a `method` so you can't instantiate it. The correct way to access that `method` would be by instantiating `AuctionSale`and proceeding to call the method calculateFee

```
AuctionSale auctioneer = new AuctionSale();
brokerFee = auctioneer.calculateFee();

System.out.printf("Item Number: %s, Description: %s, Broker fee: %d %n", 
                   itemNumber, description, brokerFee);
```

[Here](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3a_OOPBasics.html) is a good website which teaches about object oriented programming in java. I would suggest reading up on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting error at this line -

```
brokerFee = brokerFee.calculateFee();
```

Then, probably your brokerFee object which is calling calculateFee() is not an object of class AuctionSale. Correct way should be -

```
AuctionSale brokerFee = new AuctionSale();
double value = brokerFee.calculateFee();
```

If you are getting error at this line -

```
calculateFee brokerFee = new calculateFee();
```

Then, JVM expects 'calculateFee' to be a class, because you are calling a constructor. But you do not have a class by that name I suppose. You have a class AuctionSale with method calculateFee(). Hence the error.

I guess that if you change

```
calculateFee brokerFee = new calculateFee();

brokerFee = brokerFee.calculateFee();
```

to this -

```
AuctionSale brokerFee = new AuctionSale();
double value = brokerFee.calculateFee();
```

You should be okay.